# SELECT POR FILA MYSQL

Tags: mysql

En la siguiente tabla tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco una salida como la siguiente imagen, tengo el código:
SELECT diasemana AS día,codmodulo,numerohora FROM horarios GROUP BY numerohora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso se llama tabla pivotante.. busca respecto a eso

Comment: gracias ahora lo reviso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que MySQL no tiene implementado el operador `PIVOT` ni la función `CROSSTAB()` una alternativa es hacer **agregación selectiva**:

```
SELECT diasemana
     , group_concat( if(numerohora=1,codmodulo,null) ) as "1"
     , group_concat( if(numerohora=2,codmodulo,null) ) as "2"
     , group_concat( if(numerohora=3,codmodulo,null) ) as "3"
     , group_concat( if(numerohora=4,codmodulo,null) ) as "4"
     , group_concat( if(numerohora=5,codmodulo,null) ) as "5"
     , group_concat( if(numerohora=6,codmodulo,null) ) as "6"
  FROM horarios
  GROUP BY diasemana
```